# Bash script not passing correct parameters to ansible-playbook

Tags: bash, ansible

```
play -e jsmith hostname --extra-vars "user=hostname.biz command=hostname"
```

I am trying to run the above bash script that is a wrapper around the ansible-playbook command that also is able to run an external command to generate dynamic inventory files (we are not using the standard dynamic inventory module). The problem seems to be coming from bash, though. The playbook here is "hostname" and the error i keep having is "ERROR! the playbook: command=hostname could not be found". Here is the script I am using where I am trying to store the arguments to the script after i receive the -e option.

**EDIT 1**

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Description: Abstraction of ansible-playbook with knowledge of environment specific variables. 
#

prelude export

export PATH=$PATH:$ANSIBLE_HOME/bin
ANSARGS=""
ENVIRONMENT=$(envname)
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
  case "$1" in
    -e)
      ENVIRONMENT=$2
      shift 2
      ;;
    -p)
      PLAYBOOK=$2
      shift 2
      ;;
    *)
      ANSARGS+="###$1"
      shift
       ;;
  esac
done
REPLACE=' '
ANSARGSARR=($ANSARGS)

TO_DISPLAY="${ANSARGS//'###'/$REPLACE}"
echo $TO_DISPLAY
PLAYBOOKFILE=$IR_ANSIBLE_PLAYBOOKS/"$PLAYBOOK".yml
ANSIBLE_OPTS="-M $IR_ANSIBLE_MODULES -i $(dynamicinventory -e $ENVIRONMENT)"

if [ ! -f $PLAYBOOKFILE ]; then
    ansible-playbook ${ANSIBLE_OPTS} $*
else
    set -x
    ansible-playbook ${ANSIBLE_OPTS} $PLAYBOOKFILE ${TO_DISPLAY}
fi
```

`$TO_DISPLAY` is showing the correct parameter to be passed to ansible-playbook but set-x is displaying incorrect quoting and the command fails when this script is called using the following:

```
play -e jsmith -p status --extra-vars '"script=start hello=world"'
```

`$TO_DISPLAY` showing `--extra-vars "script=start hello=world"`

set -x showing `+ ansible-playbook -M ansible-conf/modules -i ansible-conf/custom_inventory/jsmith/inventory ansible-conf/playbooks/status.yml --extra-vars **'"**script=start**'** **'**hello=world**"'**`

Comment: Try putting `set -x` before the call to `ansible-playbook` so Bash will print out the exact call it's making.  (`set +x` to undo)

Comment: @EtanReisner im not forcing people to do anything thats legitimate ansible-playbook syntax..

Comment: When you shove `user=hostname.biz command=hostname` into `ANSARGS` and then split that on spaces it becomes *two* arguments. So `${ANSARGS[@]:1}` expands into *three* words: `--extra-vars`, `user=hostname.biz` and `command=hostname`. I assume that's not what you actually want though.

Comment: @EtanReisner I've added another attempt based on some new logic.

Comment: Seriously, stop trying to shove separate arguments into a string and then make then an array again. Just keep them an array in the first place if you need them passed through as given to you. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for why you can't round-trip through a string variable like that. (i.e. Don't `ANSARGS+=$1` and then `ANSARRAY=($ANSARGS)` just `ANSARRAY+=("$1")` in the argument loop.)

Answer (score 0):

It is arduous to first agglutinate and later disperse all parameters while at the same time wanting to preserve their original apportionment. Better store the parameters to separate array elements, thus keeping embedded blanks (as in `user=hostname.biz command=hostname`). Replace

```
      ANSARGS+="###$1"
```

with

```
      ANSARGSARR[${#ANSARGSARR[*]}]=$1
```

and remove

```
ANSARGSARR=($ANSARGS)
```

and replace

```
    ansible-playbook ${ANSIBLE_OPTS} $PLAYBOOKFILE ${TO_DISPLAY}
```

with

```
    ansible-playbook ${ANSIBLE_OPTS} $PLAYBOOKFILE "${ANSARGSARR[@]}"
```

- so you can invoke your script e. g. with the command line

```
play -e jsmith -p hostname --extra-vars "user=hostname.biz command=hostname"
```